# how to use CURL lib sending URL from database?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, curl

I am trying to get data from Multiple URLs but when i give the dynamic URL to CURL lib it will return me #null. if give the hard single code URL it's return me the data.

```
 public function index() 
   {
          $id="1234567899555";
            $data=$this->db->select('*')->from('URL')->where('is_delete',0)->get()->result();
       foreach($data as $values){

            $URL=$values->URL.$id;
            //var_dump($URL); die();

            $cSession = curl_init(); 
            //step2
            curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
            curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
            //var_dump(CURLOPT_URL); die();
            //step3
            $result=curl_exec($cSession);
            //step4
            curl_close($cSession);
            //step5
            //var_dump($result); die();
            $slm=json_decode($result);    
            var_dump($slm); die();  

       }




   }
```

Comment: Have you debugged the url variable to verify, that the url you expect is in it?

Comment: Without knowing what your data looks like and what you have debugged (are the URL's you get from the DB correct?), it's pretty impossible for us to know what's going on.

Comment: my URL is correct i have check it many time. even i have get the result if give hard code URL in CURL lib

Comment: So you have used this exact code with hard coded URL's (which are identical to what you get from the DB) and it worked?

Comment: Your adding the $id to the end of the URL without any sort of delimiter, is this how it should be done?

Comment: As @NigelRen says, possibility for expected URL is being `$values->URL.'/'.$id;`? If not working, just comment cURL code in for loop and make `echo $URL = $values->URL.$id;`.

Comment: curl offers a lot for you in the way of debugging info, but can be difficult to understand what went wrong, even when you are looking at the debugging info. May I suggest that you try guzzle, https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle ? It is easy to use with CodeIgniter, and I think it will be better for you.